# Is localeCompare with defaults exact same as string < string

Tags: javascript

I was trying to figure out if `a.localeCompare(b)` was exactly the same as `a < b` when `a` and `b` are both strings.

In my tests it is show it is, however I can't any source that verifies this as truth.

```
const a = 'noit';
const b = 'saab';

const shouldAGoToLowerIndex_compare = a < b;
const shouldAGoToLowerIndex_localeCompare = a.localeCompare(b) === -1;
```

Per articles like - https://medium.freecodecamp.org/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839 - using mathematical operators like `<` `<=` `>` `>=` always coerce to number.

The reason I ask is because I want to do lexical compare in a `.sort` custom function, but I wanted to understand.

Comment: It is different and also depends on the user’s locale when you don’t [pass one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). Try `'é'.localeCompare('f')` vs. `'é' < 'f'`. (There is definitely no number conversion involved.)

Comment: Also, per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare): *"**DO NOT rely on exact return values of `-1` or `1`.** Negative and positive integer results vary between browsers (as well as between browser versions) because the W3C specification only mandates negative and positive values. Some browsers may return -2 or 2 or even some other negative or positive value."*

Comment: "*using mathematical operators like < <= > >= always coerce to number.*" - uh, no. They coerce the both operands to primitives, and then one operand to a number only if the other already is a number (or non-string). If you compare string against string, the two strings are compared by lexicographic order, without any numbers involved.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi! So if I wanted in my custom sort to fallback to lexical sort I would just do `a < b`?

Comment: @Noitidart Yes, sure. As long as both operands are of the same type, don't worry about coercion.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi I have made a comment in the article I linked to add this correction - https://medium.com/@Noitidart/i-think-we-need-to-make-a-special-mention-here-that-if-both-are-strings-then-it-does-lexical-398eb8057dc5

Comment: Thanks also @TylerRoper I did not know that about `localeCompare`! Helps me catch an future bug!